# How do I use the EMGUcv ImageBox control to display an image that comes from a seperate image capture event thread

Tags: vb.net, opencv, emgucv

I have an event thread that fires when an image is received from the USB camera. This works well.

However, in that same event capture thread I would like to display that image in the UI Form that has a emgu `ImageBox` control. I cannot code directly to `ImageBox1.Image = capturedImage` because the `ImageBox` is in the UI Form not in the `OnImageEvent` thread.

Do I use some type of Invoke/Delegate here to jump threads?  (I am still learning to use these)

But I cannot find any reference to an Invoke on the emgu `ImageBox` control. Does anyone have any experience with using the emgu `Imagebox` in this cross treading type of application?

Current code:

```
' This method defines an image event. In it, the image that
' triggered the event is converted and saved before incrementing
' the count. Please see Acquisition_CSharp example for more
' in-depth comments on the acquisition of images.
Protected Overrides Sub OnImageEvent(capturedImage As ManagedImage)

    Console.WriteLine("Image event occurred...")

    ImageBox2.Image = ConvertToOpenCVMat(capturedImage)

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: there does not seem to be one for the emgu ImageBox.  can anyone confirm this

Comment: You can invoke any control, it doesn't necessarily have to be the one you're going to modify. The important thing is that you invoke to the UI thread. -- As EmguCV's `ImageBox` doesn't appear to have an `Invoke` method you can just invoke _**the form itself**_ instead: `Me.Invoke(<stuff here>)` or: `<target form>.Invoke(<stuff here>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Save image data received from the USB camera to a public variable in a module; that variable can be directly accessed by the Main thread (UI Form thread) to be displayed. The only thing you have to handle is to avoid collisions between the two threads (the secondary thread wants to save image data to the variable, while the main thread wants to read from it; you can do this using a semaphore).

Comment: Both WinForms and WPF have thread-safe methods for dealing with cross-thread calls. Why re-invent the wheel when doing so is both time consuming and potentially "unsafe"? -- See my example on [**the Stack Overflow documentation**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201704262256035702174).

Comment: I am able to make it work using the method Raffaello described above by saving off a public variable and displaying it in the UI Form thread with the emgu ImageBox control.  This confirms that my onImageEvent() is capturing the image from the USB camera correctly.     --  Howeve, I agree with Visual Vincent that there should be a way to do this with Invoke, but I cannot seem to find a way to use emgu ImageBox control with Invoke, can any with emgu knowledge confirm if this is possible?  Thanks